# Removing read-only editor tooltip (monaco-alert) from the monaco-editor

Tags: javascript, css, monaco-editor

I am trying to remove the 'monaco-alert' (the tooltip on the read-only-editor that shows 'can not edit in the read-only editor) from a read-only monaco-editor.

I tried to remove the tooltip that says 'cannot edit in a read-only editor using CSS. But, it seems that the CSS, although applied, is not working.

Given below is the screenshot of the issue that I am facing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFtjN.png)

Below given is the editor options that I am setting

```
value: this.configOriginal, language: 'json', theme: this.theme, scrollBeyondLastLine: false, contextmenu: false, readOnly: true, cursorWidth: 0,
```

And given below is the CSS that I am trying to use to hide the tooltip:

```
.monaco-alert { display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; }
```

Could anyone please help me achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain a little bit more with code and images

Comment: @Awais I have updated the question, thank you for looking into.

Comment: Did you try `IEditorHoverOptions` false like this https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditorhoveroptions.html as its an open issue on git-hub https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1742

Comment: @Awais, yes I did try `IEditorHoverOptions`, but it did not work.
Yes, I filed the issue on the GitHub, if they could help me in any way.

Comment: Actually that is the editor where we cant inspect so these properties were handle through attributes only like true false etc. So may be this functionality is not supported.